# software to share files between android and windows

Tags: windows, android, offline, sharing

is there any **airdrop alternative** that can work with android and windows? 
I want a software that exactly works like airdrop that uses bluetooth for connection and wifi to share files wirelessly **without** need of third device (router or access point).

Comment: What do you mean by share - via a program, ftp, ssh, usb, samba ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I use TotalCommander (for Android) with the TotalCmd-Lan plugin to transfer files back and forth between android devices and Windows PCs.  Bit clunky, but does the job. Nothing needed on the Windows PC.